# Handling UnicodeEncodeError with sampling tool

Tags: pyqgis, point

I'm using QGIS and I keep getting an error when using the point sampling tool, its keeping me from getting the sampling done.

Does anyone has an idea what is it about?

[image: error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick workaround: change `str(self.inSample.currentText())` to `str(self.inSample.currentText().encode('ascii', 'replace'))`. It's 'lossy' in that non-ASCII characters will be converted to `_`, but at least it'll run.

However, there really shouldn't be that `str()` operation to begin with if `.currentText()` returns a unicode object to start with, that's a lossy downcast. Another option is to use [the `locale` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale) in the Python window before running the tool to set your language/preferred string encoding so `str()` does the right thing.

I'd file a bug with the tool author.